# New power supply won't start

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I replaced my power supply with a new one. I connected all cable to the motherboard 24-pin and Molex, HDD and DVD power cable, then I started my PC and I used it for about one hour.

After I shut down my pc, and I wanted to start it again. But the PC is not starting and the motherboard LED won't light up.  The PSU was set to 230V because I live in Europe.

My new power supply is dead? How could that be?

Specs:

- CPU: Core 2 Duo
- PSU: ATX 470W
- Motherboard: Asus P5QL PRO.

Comment: my new PSU has a similar problem. Look at my question here: (http://superuser.com/questions/523379/strange-smps-behavior)

Comment: in my case i think the problem is the gpu, because when I detach the gpu the pc start.

Comment: You did say that the computer can start without the GPU plugged in. I am thinking that the PSU is not powerful enough to power the computer with the GPU. What kind of GPU is it?

Comment: Do you still have the old PSU? If you do I would recommend checking the watts on the old one. If it is more then the one you have then I would get a PSU that is the same in terms of watts as the old one or more

Comment: the old one is 450w the new is 500w. I try the psu without my pc I connect green and black cable, but its not starting. Is dead, but I don't know why. Maybe electricity problem in the haus?

Comment: the video card had been broken this caused the problem